# Has Cartthrob been updated to work with ExpressionEngine 3.x?

Tags: cartthrob

We are currently running 2.6 on EE 2.10.1 and are looking to upgrade to 3.x. I can see 2.7 is available to download but does that have full EE 3 support?

And if so, is there a migration guide? We use a number of Cartthrob hooks too so we'd need to understand any changes that may affect our own add-ons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I work at Vector; we own CartThrob)

We haven't released an EE3 version yet but we're actively working on it and pretty close. We hope to share a more exact timeline with the community very shortly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's available yet, but they're working on it: https://twitter.com/cartthrob/status/654290601026977792